# how to show path in browse button textbox

Tags: asp.net

i have a browse button and i need to browse the file and save it.i succesfully saved the path to database but at the time of edit i am not able to get the saved path in browse button textbox.so how can i do?

my browser code is like this:

```
 ![<asp:FileUpload ID="DocumentUpload" runat="server" /></td>][1]
```

my view code is like this:

```
 ![private void ViewDocumentInfo(int documentId)
    {
        try
        {
            TbldocumentmasterInfo cMaster = cmService.GetDocumentInfoById(documentId);
            if (cMaster != null)
            {

                this.TxtEntryDate.Text = Common.DispDate(cMaster.Entrydate);
                this.TxtDocumentName.Text = cMaster.Documentname;
                this.TxtDocumentCode.Text = cMaster.Documentcode;
                this.TxtDescription.Text = cMaster.Description;
                //this.TxtPath.Text = cMaster.Fullpath;
                //DocumentUpload.PostedFile.FileName.Substring(DocumentUpload.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) = cmInfo.Fullpath;
                this.DocumentUpload.HasFile.ToString() = cMaster.Fullpath;
                this.DdlcategoryId.SelectedValue = Common.IsNull(cMaster.Categoryid);
                this.TxtRemarks.Text = cMaster.Remarks;


            }
            if (documentId > 0)
            {
                this.btnSave.Text = "Update";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EM.ErrLog("DocumentMaster.aspx.cs", "ViewDocumentInfo", ex);
        }
    }][2]

  [1]:


  [2]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible due to security issues. Just place a label next to it and show the path inside that.